# How to fix the access denied permission for files created inside a docker container from the host in a Laravel application?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I tried different ways so far and saw similar questions in Stackoverflow but none worked. The problem is, that when I create a file inside the docker container, I can't edit it inside the host machine.

The project is a Laravel application with the following docker-compose file for the `php` service and its docker file.

```
...
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php8.1.Dockerfile
    container_name: "php"
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    networks:
      - medyar_network
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "${MEDYAR_PHP_PORT}:9000"
 ...
```

and Dockerfile

```
    FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine
    RUN docker-php-ext-install  pdo pdo_mysql exif
    RUN apk add --no-cache pcre-dev $PHPIZE_DEPS \
            && pecl install redis \
            && docker-php-ext-enable redis.so
    
    RUN curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
    RUN alias composer='php /usr/bin/composer'
    RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www
    RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Most of the websites suggest adding the last two lines to the Dockerfile to fix the permission, however, it doesn't work. I would appreciate it if you let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Since you are using a volume to map local files to the container you need to adjust the permissions of your local files instead.

Comment: @apokryfos where should I adjust the permissions?  inside the docker container or host machine? Do you have any code snippets for doing this?

Comment: in your host machine you need to change the file permissions of files created by docker e.g. if for example the container created a log file at `storage/logs/laravel.log` you would do  `chown <my username>:www-data storage/logs/laravel.log` and `chmod 664 storage/logs/laravel.log` this will bring the file under your host user ownership and www-data group and given write permission to both user and group. (The filename is just an example you'd need to do this for all files created inside the container that you want to edit)

Comment: @apokryfos If the `LOG_CHANNEL=daily`, then are you about to tell me I need to do this every day for each log file? 
How about files created inside the docker container? I can't edit them inside the host by non-root users.

Comment: Yes, it's a pain sometimes. For log files it's not that a big issue because you don't typically need to edit them but it's problematic in other cases.

Comment: @apokryfos I solved the problem. check it out.

Comment: Can you `COPY` your code into the image, instead of injecting it via a volume mount?  What is the more specific permission error you're getting?  If the container creates a file, you should not normally expect to be able to see or edit it from the host, since the container has an isolated filesystem.

Comment: @DavidMaze No I can't copy. For the Vue-js project that is required to run `npm install` and build the project I copy the code into the image, however, for PHP projects, the deployment involves only pulling the codes from the repository not rebuilding the image. Therefore I have to mount the files not just copy them. This approach is routine in dockerizing PHP and Laravel projects. Besides that, copying the files will make the local development extremely difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, thanks to the [Fixing permissions issues with Docker Compose and PHP](https://aschmelyun.com/blog/fixing-permissions-issues-with-docker-compose-and-php/) article, the problem is solved. I added the following lines to the `.env` file:

```
UID=1000
GID=1000
```

which is obtained by commands

```
id -i
id -g
```

Next add the following arguments to the `docker-compose` file

```
user_php:
  build:
    context: ./dockerfiles
    dockerfile: php8.1.Dockerfile
    args:
      uid: "${UID-1000}"
      gid: "${GID-1000}"
```

and then modify the `php8.1.Dockerfile` as follows

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine
ARG uid
ARG gid

RUN addgroup -g ${gid} --system laravel
RUN adduser -G laravel --system -D -s /bin/sh -u ${uid} laravel
RUN sed -i "s/user = www-data/user = laravel/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN sed -i "s/group = www-data/group = laravel/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

RUN apk add libpng-dev libzip-dev zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install  pdo pdo_mysql gd zip
RUN apk add --no-cache pcre-dev $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        && pecl install redis \
        && docker-php-ext-enable redis.so

RUN curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
RUN alias composer='php /usr/bin/composer'
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www
USER laravel
```

It creates a user and group with the given `uid` and `gid`. Then modify the user that PHP is actually running on in the container and `php.ini` configuration.